# wpf - C#: Log In and Log Out History

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

I have Login and Logout history list,

```
 var data = service.PostLogDetails(UserID);
```

It return like the image shows,

[image]

```
 var listLogInItems = (from A in data orderby A.FirstName select new { Login = "Login", Name = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, ID = A.Id, LoginDate = A.LogInTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0], LoginTime = A.LogInTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] + " " + A.LogInTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2], Comments = "Never delete this Archive" }).Distinct();
        var listLogOutItems = (from A in data orderby A.FirstName select new { Login = "Logout", Name = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, ID = A.Id, LogoutDate = (A.LogOutTime ?? "Unknown").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0], LogoutTime = A.LogOutTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] + " " + A.LogOutTime.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2], Comments = "Never delete this Archive" }).Distinct();

 listView1.ItemsSource = ?
```

then, want to display these login and logout history in Combobox.

```html
  <ListView Margin="0,102,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Width="800" Height="498">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding login_Id}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem},Path=IsSelected}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="180px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="165px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LoginDate}"  />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="160px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LoginTime}"  />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="160px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LoginStatus}"  />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="110px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Comments}"  />
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

How can I bind both login and logout history in combobox? I want the output as the below image look like,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create new 2 items from 1 item and flatten them. Use `SelectMany`.

I made a sample for console app. I used method style LINQ because I'm not familiar with query style.

I think `DateTime.Parse()` (or `DateTime.TryParse()`) is better than splitting string by yourself for parsing.

```
var data = new[]
{
    new
    {
        FirstName = "firstname",
        SurName = "surname",
        Id = "id",
        LogInTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
        LogOutTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    }
};

var items = data.SelectMany((x) => new[]
{
    new
    {
        UserName = x.FirstName + " " + x.SurName,
        AccessDate = DateTime.Parse(x.LogInTime).ToShortDateString(),
        AccessTimeFrame = DateTime.Parse(x.LogInTime).ToShortTimeString(),
        Action = "Login",
        Comment = "Never delete this Archive"
    },
    new
    {
        UserName = x.FirstName + " " + x.SurName,
        AccessDate = DateTime.Parse(x.LogOutTime).ToShortDateString(),
        AccessTimeFrame = DateTime.Parse(x.LogOutTime).ToShortTimeString(),
        Action = "Logout",
        Comment = "Never delete this Archive"
    }
})
.Distinct()
.OrderBy((x) => x.UserName);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: @calctuaroid thank you for replay me. If x.LogOutTime return null then, how can I handle that like return "Unknown" like that?

Comment: @AbhilashJA Define `DateTime parsed` and then use `DateTime.TryParse()`. For instance, `AccessDate = (DateTime.TryParse(x.LogOutTime, out parsed)) ? parsed.ToShortDateString() : "Unknown"`